# How can I parse a date and assume it starts with year or day but never month?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I want to allow a user to enter a date starting with the day or with the year but I am unsure how to check this.  Do I have to manually check every format I want to allow? (slashes, dashes, MM vs M, dd vs d).  I've looked at the `Parse` method and `ParseExact` method but it's not quite what I want.  I want to be able to try and parse an acceptable format and assume it starts with the day or assume it starts with the year.  Ex. 2016/10/05 should come out as October 5th and 05-10-2016 should also come out as October 5th.  If I specify the culture info there's 2 problems, One, I can specify one of those 2 formats and two, if someone decides to go to their setting and modify their short date format, it won't work as intended anymore.  Any ideas? Maybe what I want is not possible without some manual work.

Comment: You can use parseExact and provide an array of formats - why not use this?

Comment: Just some advice: I wouldn't allow users to enter all kinds of different formats, I would make them enter in one format. In your second example, how do you know it's not May 10?

Comment: Or have them use a Date Picker.

Comment: @auX yes I can do this, thought there might be an easier way than having to specify a bunch of formats.  Thanks for the comment, at least someone else is confirming that this is the way

Comment: What is stopping you from try one ParseExact and if it fails ParseExact  the other?

Comment: @Paparazzi this is what I will do, wanted to ask the question to see if there are any tricks I haven't thought of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chain [DateTime.TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx) for each format

Comment: Note that there is an [overload of `DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes multiple formats in an array.